# RACKET Callback procedure to load canvas% via button%

Tags: button, canvas, menu, racket

I'm doing a game project in Racket and I'm stuck on how I can create a callback procedure for my button so I can go from my start menu to my game.. I have this button defined:

```
(define *starta-spelet*
  (new button%
       [parent *menyruta*]
       [label "Starta Spelet"]
       [min-width 130]))
```

And there is a callback argument for button% (look here https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/button_.html) but I dont know how I should define my procedure which takes me from my start menu (which contains panel% and fram%) to my game (which is built on a canvas).

Also, the game and the start-menu is created in separate files .rkt files

I appreciate all help I can get. Let me know if I something is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example matching your description.
Note that the changes to the content of the-frame is made
in between `start-container-sequence` and `end-container-sequence`.
This is done to prevent the system in rendering the GUI before
we have added the game-canvas.

```
#lang racket
(require racket/gui)

;;; GUI

;; The frame holds either a start-panel or a game-panel
(define the-frame (new frame% [label "A frame"] [min-width 200] [min-height 200]))

;; The start-panel contains a start button
(define (make-start-panel)
  (define start-panel  (new panel%  [parent the-frame]))
  (define start-button (new button% [parent start-panel] [label "Start"]
                            [callback (λ (b e) (on-start-button b e))]))
  start-panel)

;; The game-panel contains a canvas
(define (make-game-panel)
  (define game-panel   (new panel%  [parent the-frame]))  ; will be set to the-frame later
  (define game-canvas  (new canvas% [parent game-panel] [min-width 200] [min-height 200]))
  game-panel)

;;; Event Handlers

(define (on-start-button button event)
  (send the-frame begin-container-sequence)
  (send the-frame delete-child the-start-panel)
  (make-game-panel)
  (send the-frame end-container-sequence))

;;; Begin Program
(define the-start-panel (make-start-panel))
(send the-frame show #t)
```